# Clicking on custom icon in vue-select dropdown does not trigger the custom method

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, tailwind-css, vue-select

I am developing a vue-component based on `vue-select` within which I am adding a custom info Icon, on click of the Icon I want to trigger my custom method `getInfo` but for some reason clicking on it does not trigger the method rather opens the search box the options search.

I want to trigger the `getInfo` function when the user clicks on the `Icon`, rest elsewhere when user clicks then I want the Input search bar to come into picture and accept user inputs.

I tried adding various `z-index` and other approaches from `tailwind css` but its not working. Following is the nuxt 3 component I have:

```
<template>
    <Field :name="name" v-model="item.value">
      <vSelect
        v-model="item"
        :options="options"
        :getOptionLabel="option.text"
        class="w-full bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 rounded p-1 z-10"
        appendToBody
      >
        <template #search="{ attributes, events }" class="z-10">
          <Icon
            v-if="displayInfoIcon"
            icon="ph:info"
            width="18"
            height="18"
            @click.native.stop.prevent="getInfo"
            class="absolute right-1 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/3 cursor-pointer z-100"
          />
          <input
            class="vs__search w-full z-10"
            v-bind="attributes"
            v-on="events"
          />
        </template>
      </vSelect>
    </Field>

    <div class="text-center">
      <ErrorMessage :name="name" class="text-red-500 mt-2 italic" />
    </div>
</template>
          
<script setup>
import { Icon } from "@iconify/vue";
import { Field, ErrorMessage } from "vee-validate";
import vSelect from "vue-select";

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: [String, Boolean, Number, Object, null], 
    required: false,
  },
  defaultSelection: {
    type: [Object, null], 
    required: false,
  },
  options: {
    type: Array,
    required: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  displayInfoIcon: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: false,
  },
});

const emits = defineEmits([
  "update:modelValue"
]);

const defaultSelectionRef = computed(() => {
  return props.modelValue
});
const item = ref(defaultSelectionRef.value);

// Watch the modelValue prop and update field when it changes
watch(
  () => props.modelValue,
  (newVal) => {
    const selectedValue =
      newVal !== undefined
        ? props.options.find((obj) => obj.value === newVal)
        : props.options[0];
    item.value = selectedValue;
  }
);

// Emit the updated modelValue when the item changes
watchEffect(() => {
  const selectedValue = item.value ?? props.options[0];
  const selected =
    selectedValue.value != undefined ? selectedValue.value : selectedValue;
  emits("update:modelValue", selected);
  emits("onItemChange", selectedValue, props.additionalParam);
});

//On click of the info icon navigate to respective Ontology link
const getInfo = () => {
  console.log("Select Dropdown With Search");
  console.log("Name : " + props.name);
  console.log("Model Value : " + item.value);
};
</script>
        
<style src="vue-select/dist/vue-select.css"></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `@mousedown.native.stop.prevent` and that worked fine for me.

```
<Icon
icon="ph:info"
@mousedown.native.stop.prevent="getInfo"
class="absolute right-1 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/3 cursor-pointer z-10 pointer-events-auto"
/>
```